# Класс неправильно использует память

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, memory-management

Создал класс massiv. Написал к нему несколько методов и все работает правильно до тех пор, пока не объявлю какую-либо другую переменную внутри этой функции. Ощущение, что сдвигаются ячейки памяти. Например, при корректном выводе, результат функции find3 возвращает:
uif
iii
Присваиваю результат функции переменной f3.

После объявления другой переменной f3 может вывести 
uif
// тут залипает до бесконечности или выводит чушь.

Также присутствует ошибка в деструкторе: Если раскомментить delete [] array, то программа вылетает и ругается на память. Подозреваю, что собака здесь зарыта.

```
    class massiv
{
private:
int size = 0;
string* array = new string[size];

public:
massiv()
{
    size = 0;
    array[size] = "";
}

~massiv()
{
    size = 0;
    //delete [] array; ЕСЛИ РАСКОММЕНТИТЬ, ТО ПРОГРАММА НАЧИНАЕТ ВЫЛЕТАТЬ, РУГАЕТСЯ НА ПАМЯТЬ
}

void add(string text)
{
    array[size] = text;
    size++;
}

void show()
{
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        cout << array[i] << endl;
}

void set(int num, string text)
{
    array[num] = text;
}

void del(int num)
{
    if (num < 0) {
        cout << "uncorrect int\n";
        return;
    }
    if (num > size-1) {
        cout << "uncorrect int\n";
        return;
    }
    if (num == size-1) {
        array[size] = "";
        size--;
    }
    if (num < size-1) {
        for (int i=num; i<size-1; i++)
            array[i] = array[i+1];
        size--;
    }
}

string items(int x)
{
    return array[x];
}

int count()
{
    return size;
}

bool eof(int i)
{
    if (i == size)
        return true;
    return false;
}
};
//=======================================================

string itos(int num)
{
    ostringstream ss;
    ss << num;
    return ss.str();
}
//=====================================

massiv loadToMassiv(string trace, unsigned int num)
{
massiv x;

char buff[num];

ifstream fin(trace);

while (!fin.eof()) {
    fin >> buff;
    x.add(buff);
}

fin.close();
return x;
}
//===================================

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
string inputWord = "uif gjoe po uif ufyu iii"; //Find on the the text
massiv f3, f2, sm3, sm2, sm1;

sm3 = somechar(inputWord, 3);
f3 = find3(inputWord);

//sm3.show(); ТУТ ОБА МАССИВА ВЫДАЮТ КОРРЕКТНЫЙ РЕЗУЛЬТАТ
//f3.show();
encript(inputWord, f3, f2, sm3, sm2, sm1);    
return 0;
}
//========================

massiv somechar(string str, int col)
{
massiv chars;

string x;
int counter;
string milk;

for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {

switch (col)
    {
        case 1:
            while (str[i] == ' ')
                i++;
            break;
        case 2:
            while ((str[i] == ' ') || (str[i+1] == ' '))
                   i++;
            break;
        case 3:
            while ((str[i] == ' ') || (str[i+1] == ' ') || (str[i+2] == '  '))
                i++;
            break;

    }

    if (i == str.length()-(col-1)) {

        for (int i=0; i<chars.count(); i+=2) {
            milk = chars.items(i);
            for (int j=i+2; j<chars.count(); j+=2) {
                if (milk == chars.items(j)) {
                    chars.del(j);
                    chars.del(j);
                    j-=2;
                }
            }
        }

        //chars.show();
        return chars;
    }

    x = str.substr(i, col);
    chars.add(x);
    counter = 0;

    for (int j=i+1; j<str.length(); j++) {
        if (str.substr(j, col) == x.substr(0, col))
            counter++;
    }
    chars.add(itos(counter+1));
}
return chars; // no exit
}
//=========================

massiv find3(string str)
{
massiv f3;
string milk;

if ((str[0] != ' ') && (str[3] == ' '))
    f3.add(str.substr(0, 3));

if ((str[str.length()] != ' ') && (str[str.length()-4] == ' '))
    f3.add(str.substr(str.length()-3, 3));

for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
    if ((str[i] == ' ') && (str[i+4] == ' '))
        f3.add(str.substr(i+1, 3));

for (int i=0; i<f3.count(); i++) {
    milk = f3.items(i);
    for (int j=i+1; j<f3.count(); j++) {
        if (milk == f3.items(j)) {
            f3.del(j);
            j--;
        }
    }
}

return f3;
}
//=======================

void encript(string str, massiv f3, massiv f2, massiv sm3, massiv sm2, massiv sm1)
{
sm3.show(); // КОРРЕКТНЫЙ РЕЗУЛЬТАТ
string milkstr = str; //ОБЪЯВЛЯЮ ПЕРЕМЕННУЮ ЛЮБОГО ТИПА
sm3.show(); // ВЫДАЕТ НЕКОРРЕКТНЫЙ РЕЗУЛЬТАТ
//-------------------
// МОЖНО ОБЪЯВИТЬ ПЕРЕМЕННУЮ ВНУТРИ ФУНКЦИИ - РЕЗУЛЬТАТ ТАКОЙ ЖЕ
massiv predlog2 = loadToMassiv("/Users/denis/Desktop/Encript/2predlog.txt", 3);
predlog2.show(); // КОРРЕКТНЫЙ РЕЗУЛЬТАТ
//-------------------
massiv predlog3 = loadToMassiv("/Users/denis/Desktop/Encript/3predlog.txt", 4);
predlog2.show(); // НЕКОРРЕКТНЫЙ РЕЗУЛЬТАТ
//-------------------
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста укажите в тегах язык. Люди пишут не только на С++

Comment: Я давно с си не работал, да и работал чуть-чуть, но разве `string* array = new string[size];` правильное создание массива? Вы же создаете массив определенного размера (вроде даже нулевого), а потом пытаетесь добавить в него что-то не изменяя размеры массива, т.е. добавляете что-то за пределы массива и тем самым портите всю память. Укажите максимальный размер массива и добавляйте пока не превысите этот размер, тогда должно работать (если еще в другом месте ошибок нет)

Comment: У вас проблемы с выделением памяти `new string[size]` , где size = 0. Память под добавляемые строки нигде не выделяется. И вполне ожидаемые проблемы с освобождением памяти.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас нету конструктора копирования. В результате используется конструктор копирования по умолчанию, который просто копирует указатель.

В результате в функциях наподобие `loadToMassiv` выделяется новый `massiv` на стеке, затем он копируется в возвращаемое значение (теперь эти два `massiv`а имеют одинаковый указатель `array`), затем исходный `massiv` удаляется, и в деструкторе удаляет и выделенный `array`. После чего эта память становится свободной и используется кем-то другим. Чтобы избежать этого, реализуйте конструктор копирования.

Далее, в конструкциях типа `sm3 = somechar(inputWord, 3)` используется оператор присваивания. Который вы тоже не реализовали, поэтому он реализуется по умолчанию тоже поэлементным копированием, что приводит к аналогичному эффекту. Чтобы избежать этого, реализуйте оператор присваивания.

Следующая проблема — `void add(string text)`. Вы не выделяете дополнительную память, а пишете в уже имеющийся массив, как будто бы выделенная память автоматически вырастет. Это не так, вам нужно знать, сколько памяти у вас выделено, и довыделять память при необходимости.

Ну и функция `void encript` выглядит странно. Вы передаёте туда `massiv`ы по значению (то есть, их копии), так что вы не сможете получить результат работы вне этой функции.

Ну и проблема, указанная другими участниками: вы в конструкторе обращается к невыделенной памяти. Для работы с индексом 0 вам нужна длина массива по крайней мере 1.

---

Конструктор копирования будет вызываться в тех местах, где экземпляр вашего класса явно или неявно копируется в другой экземпляр. Например, при вызове функции `encript` вы передаёте туда `massiv` по значению, то есть, происходит копирование. Но не в ситуации с присваиванием через `=` — в этом случае вызывается оператор присваивания. В обоих случаях вы должны скопировать данные из одного экземпляра класса в другой.

Конструктор копирования определяется так:

```
    int size;
    string* array;

public:
    massiv()
    {
        size = 0;
        array = nullptr;
    }

    ~massiv()
    {
        // удаление nullptr безопасно
        delete [] array;
    }

    // конструктор копирования
    massiv(const massiv& other)
    {
        size = other.size;
        if (size == 0)
        {
            array = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            array = new string[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                array[i] = other.array[i];
        }
    }

    massiv& operator= (const massiv& other)
    {
        // удаляем старые данные, если есть
        delete[] array;
        size = other.size;
        if (size == 0)
        {
            array = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            array = new string[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                array[i] = other.array[i];
        }
    }
```

Как вы видите, код вышел сложный, и содержит повторения. Для того, чтобы уменьшить количество черновой работы, есть несколько путей.

1. Вынести общий код в отдельный метод.

   ```
   private:
       int size;
       string* array;

       void copydata(int newsize, string* newarray)
       {
           size = newsize;
           if (size == 0)
           {
               array = nullptr;
           }
           else
           {
               array = new string[size];
               for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                   array[i] = other.array[i];
           }
       }

   public:
       massiv()
       {
           copydata(0, nullptr);
       }

       ~massiv()
       {
           // удаление nullptr безопасно
           delete [] array;
       }

       // конструктор копирования
       massiv(const massiv& other)
       {
           copydata(other.size, other.array);
       }

       massiv& operator= (const massiv& other)
       {
           // удаляем старые данные, если есть
           delete[] array;
           copydata(other.size, other.array);
       }
   ```
2. Перейти к более продвинутым, C++-специфическим структурам данных, как советует @Vlad from Moscow:

   ```
   private:
       vector<string> array;

   public:
       massiv() { }
       ~massiv() { }

       // конструктор копирования
       massiv(const massiv& other) : array(other.array) { }

       massiv& operator= (const massiv& other)
       {
           array = other.array;
       }
   ```
3. Когда вы освоите это, выучите ещё и семантику перемещения, это позволит написать конструктор перемещения и уменьшить количество операций копирования данных. (Но это уже продвинутая техника.)

Ещё один совет: старайтесь, если вам это не нужно, не передавать объект по значению (поскольку это ведёт к копированию), а по ссылке. Выучите разницу между этими двумя методами передачи, она очень важна. Например, функция `encript` должна бы получать свои аргументы по ссылке. Заметьте, что конструктор копирования получает свой аргумент также по ссылке — иначе для передачи аргумента конструктору копирования нужно было бы предварительно его скопировать, то есть выполнить конструктор копирования!

Comment: Если несложно, не могли бы вы поподробнее расписать про конструктор копирования и оператор присваивания. Мое первое знакомство с классами и разобраться тяжеловато:)

Comment: @DenisPetrov: Дописал ответ.

Comment: Большое спасибо, разобрался! Есть небольшой вопрос: я правильно понимаю, что в операторе  присваивания старые данные, которые мы очищаем, могут взяться при неоднократном присвоении? То есть объявляем массив х, затем присваиваем ему, например, значения массива y, а затем присваиваем значения массива z. Так вот, старые данные будут являться данными массива y?

Comment: @DenisPetrov: Если наш код такой: `x = y; x = z;` — то да, при втором присваивании старые данные будут данными массива `y` (точнее, их копией).

Answer (score 2):

Ваша программа имеет неопределенное поведение, так как она пытается обратиться к несуществующим элементам массива.

В этом фрагменте кода

```
private:
int size = 0;
string* array = new string[size];
```

создается массив, не имеющий элементов, так как  разсер массива `size` установлен равным 0.

Поэтому в конструкторе

public:

```
massiv()
{
    size = 0;
    array[size] = "";
}
```

вы пытаетесь обратиться к элементу массива, который не существует.

Согласно стандарту C++ (5.3.4 New)

> 7. ...When the value of the expression is zero, the allocation function is 
>      called to allocate **an array with no elements**.

Скорей всего, чтобы получить ту функциональность, которую вы хотите, вам надо использовать класс `std::vector<std::string>` вместо динамически распределяемого вручную массива.

Например,

```
private:
std::vector<std::string> array;
```

Тогда, например, функции `add` и `show` могли бы выглядеть довольно просто

```
void add( const string &text )
{
    array.push_back( text );
}

void show() const
{
    for ( const std::string &s : array ) std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```